Next.js redirect not working after setting success flag in useEffect
I’m working on a Next.js project where I want to redirect the user to the home page ("/") after a successful operation (e.g., user login). I’m using useEffect to trigger the redirection when the success flag becomes true.
The success flag triggers correctly, and I see the success alert, but the redirection to the home page doesn’t happen. Here’s my code for the component:
import { useRouter } from "next/router"; // or 'next/navigation' based on version
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const MyComponent = ({ success }) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (success) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        router.push("/"); // This is not redirecting
      }, 1000);
    }
  }, [success, router]);

  return (
    <div>
      {success ? <p>Success! Redirecting...</p> : <p>Please wait...</p>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;

I’m also using a common layout file that initially displays a loading screen for 1 second. Here’s the RootLayout component:
"use client";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Loader from "@/components/common/Loader";

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => setLoading(false), 1000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body suppressHydrationWarning={true}>
        {loading ? <Loader /> : children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}


What I've tried:
Ensured that router.push is being called after the success flag is true.
Checked the console for any errors or warnings—none appear.
Removed the loading screen logic from the layout, but the issue persists.
Expected behavior:
When the success flag becomes true, the component should wait 1 second, show a success message, and then redirect the user to the home page ("/").
Actual behavior:
The success alert is shown, but the redirection does not happen.
I’m using Next.js 13 with the app directory and use client components. Is there something I'm missing in handling the redirection logic or interaction between the layout and the component?

It might be happening for couple of reasons. First, add a new state isRedirecting to prevent multiple redirection attempts (Without this state, the component might attempt to redirect multiple times if the success prop changes or if the component re-renders frequently)
I rather import useRouter from next/navigation. Moved success message out and added a cleanup function :


"use client";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const MyComponent = ({ success }) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [isRedirecting, setIsRedirecting] = useState(false);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (success && !isRedirecting) {
      setIsRedirecting(true);
      const timer = setTimeout(() => {
        router.push("/");
      }, 1000);
      
      return () => clearTimeout(timer);
    }
  }, [success, router, isRedirecting]);

  if (isRedirecting) {
    return <p>Success! Redirecting...</p>;
  }

  return <p>Please wait...</p>;
};

export default MyComponent;



Also you can try to reduce the loading time to 100ms.
